# How to download office app

Tags: microsoft-office, download

I have Office 2019 online server installed but don't want to use a browser based Office.  Is it possible to download the app so it can installed and run local?

Here's the installation screen that clearly shows its the Online Server.

[image]

Here's the Win10 Apps listing

[image]

After install, here's the online Word app (not what I want)

[image]

Comment: Microsoft doesn’t sell an “online” edition of Office 2019.  When you purchased Office 2019 you were sent a download link to it.  [This](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-office-offline-installer-f0a85fe7-118f-41cb-a791-d59cef96ad1c) should work.  Office 2019 is a perpetual and only requires you to activate it once while Office 365 is a subscription based model of an updated version of Office 2019.  If you log into Office 2019 with a Microsoft Account that is an active Office 365 it will automatically be activated to the current Office 365 build.

Comment: [Office Online Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/officeonlineserver/office-online-server-overview) is a completely different product line aimed at completely different groups of people to "Office 2019". If you need Office 2019 then you should download and install that instead of Office Online Server.

Comment: @Mokubai - I didn’t even know that existed! I am now entirely confused on what the author is actually asking for.

Comment: @Ramhound I didn't know it existed either and was trying to work out why anyone would have it. The only use case I can see for it is companies that need to lower their cost of copies of Office going largely unused, can deal with the restrictions of the webapp style of office but still need their own on-prem hosting due to security or network restrictions. I honestly have no idea how you could "accidentally" install it rather than the real Office 2019.

Comment: I added details to the original question.  Now I'm confused as the what the heck I purchased.  From the MS licencesing service I downloaded what was listed as Office 2019 Standard and came with the file name "Office 2019 Standard SW_DVD5_Office_Professional_Plus_64Bit_English_-6_OfficeOnlineSvr_MLF_X21-90444"

Comment: What was the file extension of that file?

Comment: It was an ISO.  I have a lead that I will check out tomorrow.  It looks like downloads from The volume license center for office products got more complicated.   https://www.techsoup.org/support/articles-and-how-tos/how-to-download-and-install-microsoft-office-2019-products-requested-from-techsoup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method of installing Office from the Volume License Center has changed.  Its now a multi stage manual process to download and install.  1) Get the Office Deployment Tool (ODT);  2) Get the config file from the Techsoup link below and edit your product key.  3) Use setup.exe (ODT) to Download (about 30-60 mins). 2) Use ODT to configure (install).

[MS VLC Download Instructions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/DeployOffice/office2019/deploy)

[Techsoup Download Instructions](https://www.techsoup.org/support/articles-and-how-tos/how-to-download-and-install-microsoft-office-2019-products-requested-from-techsoup)

Comment: Congratulations! Currently, we use ODT to deploy or install C2R versions of Office, such as Microsoft 365 apps, Office 2019. The previous installation you showed is OOS which is installed on Windows server.